# SQL update in specific day of week

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Hello I have this table

```
TABLE `record` (
   `zpravaID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `sensorID` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `date_time` datetime NOT NULL,
   `cena` double DEFAULT NULL,
   `is_cheap` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   PRIMARY KEY (`zpravaID`), ...)
```

I would like to do an update which will for example take all records from 2016 and every record, which will be on Monday from 14:00:00 to 14:45:00 will have set the `is_cheap` to true (1).
I really have no idea, how to do that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the day of the week you can either use `WEEKDAY()` or `DAYOFWEEK()` , the difference between them is that in `DAYOFWEEK()` sunday is `1` . You can use `DATE_FORMAT` to extract only the time value, and `YEAR()` to extract the year of the date :

```
UPDATE `record` t
SET t.is_cheap = 1
WHERE DAYOFWEEK(t.date_time) = 2 
      AND DATE_FORMAT(t.date_time,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '14:00:00' AND '14:45:00'
      AND YEAR(t.date_time) = 2016
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
update record
set is_cheap = 1
where YEAR(date_time) = 2016  
and DAYNAME(date_time) = 'Monday'
and DATE_FORMAT(date_time,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '14:00:00' AND '14:45:00'
```